# Get attachment id in a Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I am designing a wallpaper website. In every post there is only one unique image which I'm trying to get the attachment ID associated with that image.

My code that gets the post's content:

```
<?php the_content( __( 'Continue Reading' , 'nuntius' ) . ' &raquo;'); ?>
```

I can get the thumbnail image's link, but not the full image's link.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );  ?>`  returns the full thumbnail image.

If you want the image url then you can use `<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' );  ?>` Let me know if this helps or not.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i don't need the thumbnail. I need the link to the attachment. Thanks to the editor i can't even understand my own question now! LOL

Comment: Hi, <?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>   this code does not return thumbnail  .  It returns full image url.  like  `http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/full.jpg` Maybe i am not understanding you correctly.  Try to explain again, We are here to help.

Comment: Thank you, it worked but in another way. I had to set my full size as featured image, so this code would return the original URL. Appreciated!

Comment: You had any custom field for the image ?

Comment: Custom field? I don't know about that, but i just had to set the image as featured, instead of directly inserting it into the post.

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id
I think this one helpfull for you Maybe describe what u want

Comment: Thank you sir, I wanted the full size image which now i can get with the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );